# Pay now vs pay later at expedia.com

Tags: hotels, expedia

So for a particular hotel on expedia.com I can "pay online now" $374 or I can "pay later" $374 (approx). The following screenshot better captures what I mean:

[image]

My question is...  why is pay later an approximation whereas pay online now isn't? If I pay later would I essentially be paying at the same rate I'd be paying at if I tried to book the hotel same day (which would be quite expensive, I'd imagine)?

Comment: I think the site might have gotten confused because both "local currencies" are the same, but this would make sense if it was the difference in paying Expedia $374 US dollars now to pass on to the hotel, or waiting until you get there paying the hotel directly an amount which depending on bank charges/exchange rate changes will probably be $374ish.

Comment: I think, the price will vary at pay later option. There may be some other charges. I have some doubt on free cancellation option.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The price you pay at the hotel through their "pay later" option will be the same price that Expedia quotes you when you make the reservation.  You will not be charged their walk in rate.

Chances are the verbiage "(approx.)" is hard coded into their html and shows on all bookings like this regardless of currency.  But it is there because exchange rates can change between now and when the hotel actually charges you and large percentage of Expedia's bookings are cross border (either hotel location or customer location).